# why value is not set in input field (already used "value":"ddd")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

can we add by default value in input field.I make a form in which I convert json to form .
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZNJO3x3IqajjdMNStJMF?p=preview
I used this plugin
https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/index.md#validation-messages

already used this

```
"value":"dddd"
```

why it is not coming pre field or default value ?

```
 $scope.schema = {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
      name: { type: "string", minLength: 2, title: "Name", description: "Name or alias" ,required:true,"value":"dddd"},
      "student": { type: "string", title: "studentname", description: "Name or student" ,required:false},

      "email": {
      "title": "Email",
      "type": "string",


      "description": "Email will be used for evil.",
      required:true
    },
      title: {
        type: "string",
        required:true,
        enum: ['dr','jr','sir','mrs','mr','NaN','dj'],

      }
    }
  };
```

an we give different message .."required :true" ."these field is required" and when user enter invalid email "please enter the valid email

Answer (score 1):

instead of `"value": "dddd"` do `default: "dddd"`

Comment: thanks working …can we give different message .."required :true" ."these field is required" and when user enter invalid email  "please enter the valid email "

Comment: please suggest answer

Comment: @digitalfresh do you know how to give different message